# Ionic V4: ion-modal just like ion-alert

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

The following `ion-alert` would be exactly what we need if the input was replaced with a textarea; however, `ion-alert` doesn't support `ion-textarea`.

How can the exact same look and feel be implemented with an `ion-modal`?

We are using Ionic without Angular (Ionic core).

**ion-alert code**

```
 const alert = await alertController.create({
   header: 'Would you be willing to leave feedback?',
   inputs: [
   {
     placeholder: 'enter text'
   }],
   buttons: [
     {
       text: 'Cancel',
       role: 'cancel',
       cssClass: 'secondary',
       handler: _ => {
         alert.dismiss();
         console.log('cancel');
       }
     }, {
       text: 'Submit',
       handler: _ => {
         alert.dismiss();
         console.log('submit');
       }
     }
   ]
 });
 alert.present();
```

[image: ion-alert]

**attempted ion-modal code**

```
const modalController = $('ion-modal-controller')[0];
await modalController.componentOnReady();

const modalElement = await modalController.create({
  showBackdrop: true,
  component:
    $(`<div>
          <h2>Would you be willing to provide feedback?</h2>

          <div>
            <ion-button>Cancel</ion-button>
            <ion-button>Submit</ion-button>
          </div>
      </div>`)[0]
});
await modalElement.present();
```

[image: ion-modal]

Answer (score 2):

In the page where you call the modal:

```js
async book() {
   const modal = await this.modalController.create({
 component: BookModal,
 componentProps: { value: 123 },
 showBackdrop: true,
 backdropDismiss: true,
 cssClass: ['booking-modal']
   });
   return await modal.present();
}
```

The key point is the **cssClass**. Then in theme/variable.scss, add the class at the end of the file like below:

```css
.booking-modal {
 --height: 50% !important;
}
```

** Note: this might not be the correct way to do it, but it works for me at this stage. Looking for a better solution.